# Apply functions to a single div at a time using radio buttons

Tags: javascript, function

The following quiz code is functioning, but I need to limit its scope to a single `<div/>` element at a time. Might not be the right term, but I am currently learning JavaScript and am figuring things out as I go.

Whenever a correct or incorrect radio button is checked, the **Correct!** or **Nice try** headings along with the feedback text and `<button>Next</button>` are displayed to the user. The chosen radio button should only enable the heading, text, and button for the single `<div/>`.

Any tips for figuring this out and simplifying my code would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

```js
function correctAnswer() {
  const correctAnswers = document.querySelectorAll('[class*="true"]');
  correctAnswers.forEach(function (correctAnswer) {
    correctAnswer.style.display = "block";
  });

  const questionFeedback = document.querySelectorAll('[class*="feedback"]');
  questionFeedback.forEach(function (feedback) {
    feedback.style.display = "block";
  });
}

function incorrectAnswer() {
  const incorrectAnswers = document.querySelectorAll('[class*="false"]');
  incorrectAnswers.forEach(function (incorrectAnswer) {
    incorrectAnswer.style.display = "block";
  });

  const questionFeedback = document.querySelectorAll('[class*="feedback"]');
  questionFeedback.forEach(function (feedback) {
    feedback.style.display = "block";
  });
}

function onNext() {
  const nextButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".js-btn--next");
  nextButtons.forEach(function (button) {
    button.style.display = "block";
  });
}

function runQuiz() {
  const questionBlocks = document.querySelectorAll(
    '[class*="rsform-block-question"]'
  );
  const answers = document.querySelectorAll(".rsform-radio");

  answers.forEach(function (answer) {
    answer.addEventListener("change", function () {
      for (let i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
        let answerValue = answers[i];
        if (answerValue.checked) {
          if (answerValue.value == "t") {
            correctAnswer();
          } else {
            incorrectAnswer();
          }
          questionBlocks.forEach(function (block) {
            block.style.display = "none";
          });
          onNext();
        }
      }
    });
  });
}

runQuiz();
```

```css
.formContainer {
  margin: 40px;
  padding: 16px;
}
.formContainer .formControls {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.formContainer .formControlLabel {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.formContainer .formControls input[type="radio"] {
  margin-right: 4px;
}
.formContainer .formControls input[type="radio"] + label {
  margin-right: 8px;
}
.formContainer p[class*="true"],
.formContainer p[class*="false"],
.formContainer p[class*="feedback"],
.formContainer .btn--next {
  display: none;
}
.formContainer.formHidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="formContainer">
    <div class="row rsform-block rsform-block-question-one">
        <div class="medium-3 columns">
            <label class="formControlLabel" data-tooltip="" aria-haspopup="true" data-disable-hover="false" tabindex="1" title="">
                What sense do owls use the most?
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="medium-9 columns formControls">
            <div aria-required="true">
                <input type="radio" name="form[question-one]" value="f" id="question-one0" class="rsform-radio">
                <label for="question-one0">Sight</label>
                <input type="radio" name="form[question-one]" value="f" id="question-one1" class="rsform-radio">
                <label for="question-one1">Smell</label>
                <input type="radio" name="form[question-one]" value="t" id="question-one2" class="rsform-radio">
                <label for="question-one2">Hearing</label>
                <input type="radio" name="form[question-one]" value="f" id="question-one3" class="rsform-radio"><label for="question-one3">Taste</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p class="question-one-true">
        <strong>Correct!</strong>
    </p>
    <p class="question-one-false">
        <strong>Nice try</strong>
    </p>
    <p class="question-one-feedback">
        Although owls have very good eyesight, they rely on their sense of hearing to find their prey. Their ears are quite large, under their feathers and right behind their eyes. One is set higher than the other and their fringed wing feathers create a silent flight in order for them to hear their fast moving prey.
    </p>
    <button class="btn--next js-btn--next">Next</button>
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="formContainer">
    <div class="row rsform-block rsform-block-question-two">
        <div class="medium-3 columns">
            <label class="formControlLabel" data-tooltip="" aria-haspopup="true" data-disable-hover="false" tabindex="1" title="">
                Which is the tallest owl in Alberta?
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="medium-9 columns formControls">
            <div aria-required="true">
                <input type="radio" name="form[question-two]" value="f" id="question-two0" class="rsform-radio">
                <label for="question-two0">Snowy Owl</label>
                <input type="radio" name="form[question-two]" value="t" id="question-two1" class="rsform-radio">
                <label for="question-two1">Great Grey Owl</label>
                <input type="radio" name="form[question-two]" value="f" id="question-two2" class="rsform-radio">
                <label for="question-two2">Great Horned Owl</label>
                <input type="radio" name="form[question-two]" value="f" id="question-two3" class="rsform-radio">
                <label for="question-two3">Hawk Owl</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p class="question-one-true">
        <strong>Correct!</strong>
    </p>
    <p class="question-one-false">
        <strong>Nice try</strong>
    </p>
    <p class="question-one-feedback">
        Great Grey Owls are found in western Alberta and are known as the ghosts of the forest. They can stand more than 80 cm (31 in) high and have a 150 cm (59 in) wingspan. Although huge looking, they have quite small feet and are made of mostly feathers.
    </p>
    <button class="btn--next js-btn--next">Next</button>
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="formContainer">
    <div class="row rsform-block rsform-block-question-three">
        <div class="medium-3 columns">
            <label class="formControlLabel" data-tooltip="" aria-haspopup="true" data-disable-hover="false" tabindex="1" title="">
                Which is the heaviest owl in Alberta?
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="medium-9 columns formControls">
            <div aria-required="true">
                <input type="radio" name="form[question-three]" value="f" id="question-three0" class="rsform-radio">
                <label for="question-three0">Great Grey Owl</label>
                <input type="radio" name="form[question-three]" value="f" id="question-three1" class="rsform-radio">
                <label for="question-three1">Boreal Owl</label>
                <input type="radio" name="form[question-three]" value="f" id="question-three2" class="rsform-radio">
                <label for="question-three2">Great Horned Owl</label>
                <input type="radio" name="form[question-three]" value="t" id="question-three3" class="rsform-radio">
                <label for="question-three3">Snowy Owl</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p class="question-one-true">
        <strong>Correct!</strong>
    </p>
    <p class="question-one-false">
        <strong>Nice try</strong>
    </p>
    <p class="question-one-feedback">
        With dense feathers keeping them warm in colder climates, a big female can weigh up to 2700 g (5.5 lb). Even then, with hollow bones and feathers, even the biggest birds don’t weigh very much.
    </p>
    <button class="btn--next js-btn--next">Next</button>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote your radio buttons' click event listener to have some awareness of its context by using `closest()` to find the closest `.formContainer` element and then operate only on the form container's children.  There's some other cruft you can clean out from your code if you attach your event listener that way, but I'll leave tidying up as an exercise for you.

```js
function correctAnswer() {
  const correctAnswers = document.querySelectorAll('[class*="true"]');
  correctAnswers.forEach(function(correctAnswer) {
    correctAnswer.style.display = "block";
  });

  const questionFeedback = document.querySelectorAll('[class*="feedback"]');
  questionFeedback.forEach(function(feedback) {
    feedback.style.display = "block";
  });
}

function incorrectAnswer() {
  const incorrectAnswers = document.querySelectorAll('[class*="false"]');
  incorrectAnswers.forEach(function(incorrectAnswer) {
    incorrectAnswer.style.display = "block";
  });

  const questionFeedback = document.querySelectorAll('[class*="feedback"]');
  questionFeedback.forEach(function(feedback) {
    feedback.style.display = "block";
  });
}

function onNext() {
  const nextButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".js-btn--next");
  nextButtons.forEach(function(button) {
    button.style.display = "block";
  });
}

function runQuiz() {
  const answers = document.querySelectorAll(".rsform-radio");

  answers.forEach(function(answer) {
    answer.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
      let target = event.target;
      let formContainer = target.closest(".formContainer");
      let trueElement = formContainer.querySelector("p[class$='-true'");
      let falseElement = formContainer.querySelector("p[class$='-false'");
      let feedbackElement = formContainer.querySelector("p[class$='-feedback'");
      let questionBlock = formContainer.querySelector('[class*="rsform-block-question"]');

      console.log("click!", target.value, target);
      //formContainer.classList.add("formHidden");

      if (event.target.value == "t") {
        //correctAnswer();
        console.log("right!");
        trueElement.style.display = "block";
        falseElement.style.display = "none";
        feedbackElement.style.display = "none";
      } else {
        console.log("wrong!");
        trueElement.style.display = "none";
        falseElement.style.display = "block";
        feedbackElement.style.display = "block";
      }

      questionBlock.style.display = "none";
      
      onNext();

    });
  });
}

runQuiz();
```

```css
.formContainer {
  margin: 40px;
  padding: 16px;
}

.formContainer .formControls {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.formContainer .formControlLabel {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.formContainer .formControls input[type="radio"] {
  margin-right: 4px;
}

.formContainer .formControls input[type="radio"]+label {
  margin-right: 8px;
}

.formContainer p[class*="true"],
.formContainer p[class*="false"],
.formContainer p[class*="feedback"],
.formContainer .btn--next {
  display: none;
}

.formContainer.formHidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="formContainer">
  <div class="row rsform-block rsform-block-question-one">
    <div class="medium-3 columns">
      <label class="formControlLabel" data-tooltip="" aria-haspopup="true" data-disable-hover="false" tabindex="1" title="">
                What sense do owls use the most?
            </label>
    </div>
    <div class="medium-9 columns formControls">
      <div aria-required="true">
        <input type="radio" name="form[question-one]" value="f" id="question-one0" class="rsform-radio">
        <label for="question-one0">Sight</label>
        <input type="radio" name="form[question-one]" value="f" id="question-one1" class="rsform-radio">
        <label for="question-one1">Smell</label>
        <input type="radio" name="form[question-one]" value="t" id="question-one2" class="rsform-radio">
        <label for="question-one2">Hearing</label>
        <input type="radio" name="form[question-one]" value="f" id="question-one3" class="rsform-radio"><label for="question-one3">Taste</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p class="question-one-true">
    <strong>Correct!</strong>
  </p>
  <p class="question-one-false">
    <strong>Nice try</strong>
  </p>
  <p class="question-one-feedback">
    Although owls have very good eyesight, they rely on their sense of hearing to find their prey. Their ears are quite large, under their feathers and right behind their eyes. One is set higher than the other and their fringed wing feathers create a silent
    flight in order for them to hear their fast moving prey.
  </p>
  <button class="btn--next js-btn--next">Next</button>
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="formContainer">
  <div class="row rsform-block rsform-block-question-two">
    <div class="medium-3 columns">
      <label class="formControlLabel" data-tooltip="" aria-haspopup="true" data-disable-hover="false" tabindex="1" title="">
                Which is the tallest owl in Alberta?
            </label>
    </div>
    <div class="medium-9 columns formControls">
      <div aria-required="true">
        <input type="radio" name="form[question-two]" value="f" id="question-two0" class="rsform-radio">
        <label for="question-two0">Snowy Owl</label>
        <input type="radio" name="form[question-two]" value="t" id="question-two1" class="rsform-radio">
        <label for="question-two1">Great Grey Owl</label>
        <input type="radio" name="form[question-two]" value="f" id="question-two2" class="rsform-radio">
        <label for="question-two2">Great Horned Owl</label>
        <input type="radio" name="form[question-two]" value="f" id="question-two3" class="rsform-radio">
        <label for="question-two3">Hawk Owl</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p class="question-two-true">
    <strong>Correct!</strong>
  </p>
  <p class="question-two-false">
    <strong>Nice try</strong>
  </p>
  <p class="question-two-feedback">
    Great Grey Owls are found in western Alberta and are known as the ghosts of the forest. They can stand more than 80 cm (31 in) high and have a 150 cm (59 in) wingspan. Although huge looking, they have quite small feet and are made of mostly feathers.
  </p>
  <button class="btn--next js-btn--next">Next</button>
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="formContainer">
  <div class="row rsform-block rsform-block-question-three">
    <div class="medium-3 columns">
      <label class="formControlLabel" data-tooltip="" aria-haspopup="true" data-disable-hover="false" tabindex="1" title="">
                Which is the heaviest owl in Alberta?
            </label>
    </div>
    <div class="medium-9 columns formControls">
      <div aria-required="true">
        <input type="radio" name="form[question-three]" value="f" id="question-three0" class="rsform-radio">
        <label for="question-three0">Great Grey Owl</label>
        <input type="radio" name="form[question-three]" value="f" id="question-three1" class="rsform-radio">
        <label for="question-three1">Boreal Owl</label>
        <input type="radio" name="form[question-three]" value="f" id="question-three2" class="rsform-radio">
        <label for="question-three2">Great Horned Owl</label>
        <input type="radio" name="form[question-three]" value="t" id="question-three3" class="rsform-radio">
        <label for="question-three3">Snowy Owl</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p class="question-three-true">
    <strong>Correct!</strong>
  </p>
  <p class="question-three-false">
    <strong>Nice try</strong>
  </p>
  <p class="question-three-feedback">
    With dense feathers keeping them warm in colder climates, a big female can weigh up to 2700 g (5.5 lb). Even then, with hollow bones and feathers, even the biggest birds don’t weigh very much.
  </p>
  <button class="btn--next js-btn--next">Next</button>
</fieldset>
```